# Why am I not getting the day of the week I expect from setting this calendar object?

Tags: java, calendar

Edit: Thanks- I understand it a lot more now.  Its very confusing when you first start! Thanks for the help.  I am going to keep the question up as is ( in peril of more downvotes) as it might help others. There are some other  libraries that everyone seems to recommend for date time

---

I am struggling with the Java calendar function- its seems to be returning wrong data the bottom figure should be a thursday according to calendar, but is returning as a saturday!

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
       cal.set(2012,2,23); // 0 = January

      String weekdays[]={"sunday","monday", "tuesday", "wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday",};

        Integer Weekdaycurrent1=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        System.out.println("today is a "+weekdays[Weekdaycurrent1]); //Prints today is Saturday, when it should be a thursday
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to assume that a class that's been part of the JDK since 1.0 is "wrong".  Someone would have found such a trivial bug years ago.  You're the one that's wrong.  Assume that you're the problem and you'll make faster progress.

Comment: Your post title sounds as if you've found a bug in Java, which of course isn't true. Consider editing your thread and re-titling it, "Which of my assumptions regarding the Calendar class are wrong", or something similar. Do this and I'll bet the down-votes will go away.

Comment: Thanks- I understand it a lot more now.  Its very confusing when you first start! Thanks for the help.  I am going to keep the question up ( in peril of more downvotes) as it might help others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, `DAY_OF_WEEK` is `1` based:

```
public final static int SUNDAY = 1;
```

Secondly, `2012-03-23` (yes, Mar not Feb) as set by `cal.set(2012, 2, 23)` was a *Friday*

**Your code is behaving correctly.**

Edited: For those too lame to read the question properly, calling `cal.set(2012,2,23)` sets the date to `2012-03-23`, because the `month` parameter is zero-based (ie Jan = 0, Feb = 1, Mar = 2, etc)

Comment: @Jack Dude, `cal.set(2012, 2, 23)` sets it to *March*, **not** *February*, because the month parameter is zero-based (Jan = 0)

Comment: There has been some overlapping between human month convention and Java month convention here ;) I actually know that it is zero based but when I've read your answer I supposed your `2012-03-23` was zero based too just because I had been lazy, sorry about that!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It just seems weird the implementation of calendar on java. Why not just make everything zero based or make everything 1 based. Doesn't make sense really.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong assumption on your part.  Read the javadocs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util

```
public static final int SUNDAY          1
public static final int MONDAY          2
public static final int TUESDAY         3
public static final int WEDNESDAY       4
public static final int THURSDAY        5
public static final int FRIDAY          6
public static final int SATURDAY        7
```