# DAY_OF_WEEK always returns 7 in Java GregorianCalendar

Tags: java, calendar, dayofweek, gregorian-calendar

So I want to do something with Java GregorianCalendar that seems to be going way harder than it should. I want to get the day of the week from the month and date. But it won't do that. I know that people often get the wrong answer to this because they don't know month is numbered from 0 while DAY_OF_WEEK is numbered from 1 (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576408/why-am-i-not-getting-the-day-of-the-week-i-expect-from-setting-this-calendar-obj?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645608/java-get-day-of-week-is-not-accurate)). But that's not my problem. My problem is that DAY_OF_WEEK always, always, returns 7, no matter what I set the date to. When I convert the GregorianCalendar to string, DAY_OF_WEEK appears as ?, even though I have set year, month, and dayOfMonth.

The code where this is happening:

```
GregorianCalendar theDate;

public ObservableDate(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second)
{
    theDate = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, dayOfMonth, hourOfDay, minute, second);
    theDate.setFirstDayOfWeek(GregorianCalendar.SUNDAY);
    System.out.println("DAY_OF_WEEK = "+theDate.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    System.out.println(theDate.toString());
}
```

The code that calls it:

```
    ObservableDate theDate = new ObservableDate(2001, 3, 24, 9, 00, 00);
```

Output:

```
DAY_OF_WEEK = 7
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/New_York",offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=235,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/New_York,offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=?,YEAR=2001,MONTH=3,WEEK_OF_YEAR=?,WEEK_OF_MONTH=?,DAY_OF_MONTH=24,DAY_OF_YEAR=?,DAY_OF_WEEK=?,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=?,AM_PM=0,HOUR=9,HOUR_OF_DAY=9,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=?,ZONE_OFFSET=?,DST_OFFSET=?]
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are accessing the field constant instead of getting its' value. I believe you wanted to use something like,

```
System.out.println("DAY_OF_WEEK = " + theDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
```

Comment: Ah, so it's like an enum then.

Comment: Ah. Yes, that did it, thanks! (With the slight modification that I needed to use GregorianCalendar rather than Calendar.)

Comment: How do you use it? Your solution is giving me the 7 number anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is you're accessing the constant `DAY_OF_WEEK` in the `Calendar` class (`Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK`).

To properly get the day of week use the `theDate` variable's `.get()` method like so:

```
theDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

For a smart `DayOfWeek` enum object.

```
ZonedDateTime.of( 2001 , 3 , 24 , 9 , 0 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )  // Moment as seen by people in a certain region (time zone).
             .getDayOfWeek()                                                         // Extract a `DayOfWeek` enum object to represent that day-of-week of that moment.
```

For a mere integer 1-7 for Monday-Sunday.

```
ZonedDateTime.of( 2001 , 3 , 24 , 9 , 0 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )
             .getDayOfWeek()
             .getValue()                                                             // Translate that `DayOfWeek` object into a mere integer 1-7 for Monday-Sunday.
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes. `Calendar` is replaced by [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( 2001 , 3 , 24 , 9 , 0 , 0 , 0 , z );
```

The [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum defines seven objects for each day of the week.

```
DayOfWeek dow = zdt.getDayOfWeek() ;  // Get `DayOfWeek` enum object representing this moment’s day-of-week.
```

You can [ask the `DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-) to localize the name of the day.

I suggest using these `DayOfWeek` objects across your codebase rather than mere integer numbers. But if you insist, you can get a number. Unlike in `GregorianCalendar` the numbers have a fixed meaning and do not vary by locale. The meaning is 1-7 for Monday-Sunday, per the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) standard.

```
int dowNumber = zdt.getDayOfWeek().getValue() ;  // 1-7 for Monday-Sunday per ISO 8601.
```

### Immutable object

Note that *java.time* uses [*immutable objects*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). Rather than alter member variables on the object (“mutate”), calls to adjust the value results in a new object, leaving the original object unchanged.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtTomorrow = zdt.now( z ).plusDays( 1 ) ;  // Alterations result in a new object, leaving original intact. Known as *immutable objects*.
```

## Time zone

You failed to specify a time zone in your constructor’s arguments and in the arguments passed to `new GregorianCalendar`. In such cases, the JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly assigned. That default can vary by machine, and can even change at any moment *during* runtime. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

## Octal number literals

Beware of your `00` literal value. A leading zero means [*octal* base-8 number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) rather than decimal number in Java source code. You lucked-out as octal zero is also decimal zero.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).